# pull to refresh not working with small amount of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a feed view controller (implemented with a UICollectionViewController)
When i don't have enough cells to cover the hall screen height the pull to refresh isn't working.
How can i fix this?

Code:

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.postCollection.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

    func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    getPost()
}
```

EDIT:
by not working i mean that the uicollectionview cant be pulled down and the animation isn't starting.

Comment: Have you solved it ?

Comment: @ReneDohan, didnt find a solution, st.derrick answer maybe it will help you

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4

The following will force the collection view to always bounce, in this case vertically, even if the items are not filling the entire collection view height.

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Comment: Please, add a comment explaining how this code solve the problem

Comment: Worked for me..@Terru_theTerror Here is the description: If this property is set to true and bounces is true, vertical dragging is allowed even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the scroll view. The default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

this means you are most likely not refreshing the tableview in the getPost() method. After you update data, you need to make a call to `self.postCollection.reloadData()`.

Can you post code for cellForRowAtIndexPath? It's also possible that you aren't properly accounting for cells being reused.

**EDIT: I believe I've solved it**

I saw similar behavior to yours and it was related to Auto Layout and Size Classes

For me, the refresh control showed up on the right side, not centered:

Simulator:

[bad-sim http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/bad-sim.png](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/bad-sim.png)

For you, it may be showing up off screen.

Notice how this appears when looking at the Storyboard (both "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" are checked).

Xcode:

[bad-xcode http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/bad-xcode.png](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/bad-xcode.png)

One **solution** is to uncheck "Use Auto Layout". You probably need to then resize your tableview (I had to delete it and re-add it).

Then it should appear correctly.

Simulator:

[good-sim http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/good-sim.png](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/good-sim.png)

Xcode:

[good-xcode http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/good-xcode.png](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/refreshcontrol/good-xcode.png)

Lastly, here is my code (although it is missing a method for refresh:)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
    @IBOutlet var postCollection: UITableView!
        var myCollection = ["hi", "there", "bob"]
        var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            if let myTableView = self.postCollection {
                self.postCollection!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
                self.postCollection!.delegate = self
                self.postCollection!.dataSource = self

                self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
                self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
                self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
                self.postCollection.insertSubview(self.refreshControl, atIndex: 0)
            }
        }

         func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.myCollection[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.myCollection.count
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unable to see your PNG (website show unauthorized).

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    listview.addSubview(refreshControl)

}
func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
    // Your code here
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

> Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically:
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

or From Storyboard:
You should enable these two options
[image: Bounce options]